# Is it possible to use IFNULL() with a * in a SELECT statement with MySQL? If not, what is my alternative?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Here is what I have that currently works in a `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT
    movieitemdetails.barcode,
    IFNULL(movieitemdetails_custom.title, movieitemdetails.title) AS title
FROM
...
```

The problem is that I need to have my SQL be more dynamic when it comes to column names and the amount of columns I have. I need to use `*` to dynamically pull back all rows. Here is some example pseudocode to show you what I need:

```
IFNULL(movieitemdetails_custom.*, movieitemdetails.*) AS *
```

I need it to bring back all of the columns with the same name on each table and do the `IFNULL` comparison. Obviously the code above is not correct.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to make what I have more dynamic involving `*`?

**Note to certain people:** Please don't give me flak about how I shouldn't use `*`. I know in general use it's not recommended, but in this specific project it is what we're going with.

Answer (score 2):

No, the IFNULL() function accepts only two scalar expressions, not wildcard expressions like `*`.

To make this query more dynamic, your options are:

- Build the query with application code, appending an IFNULL() expression for each such pair of columns. Then submit the query.

Or:

- Fetch all the columns independently with `SELECT * ...` and then sort out which ones to use in application code.

Comment: A third option is do two queries, one to check for that condition, and a second query to fetch the data from the appropriate table.

Comment: I may be able to use `SHOW columns FROM movieitemdetails` and `SHOW columns FROM movieitemdetails_custom` and then compare the two to see which have the same column names, and then build the query dynamically off of that. Sounds strange but possible... but probably not worth the extra calls and loops every time.

Comment: Many frameworks keep a static list of columns in a config file or something. You either have to know what columns you have, or else you have to bear the cost of discovering columns dynamically all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do each column individually, like so:

```
SELECT
    movieitemdetails.barcode,
    IFNULL(movieitemdetails_custom.title, movieitemdetails.title) AS title
    IFNULL(movieitemdetails_custom.col2, movieitemdetails.col2) AS col2
    IFNULL(movieitemdetails_custom.col3, movieitemdetails.col3) AS col3
FROM
...
```

Not sure exactly what you mean by having it be more dynamic regarding the amount of columns though.. a SELECT statement cannot have a variable number of columns, so if you want that behavior you would need to use a stored procedure or build your SQL dynamically.

Comment: What I meant was that `SELECT *` will bring back all columns without knowing how many there are... meaning the number is variable.

Comment: @Ethan - OK gotcha. It would be nice to have something like what you describe, but I don't think it exists in any databases that I'm aware of.